# Blocking the main thread immediately in the first view cause a flash of black screen on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

Adding the following code to a new project cause a flash of a black screen. It seems to be caused by the fade out animation of the splash screen. Unfortunately, the long process must be on main thread. It is possible to avoid it by delaying it but it is unreliable and lengthens the loading process.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // A spinner is shown
    // This most probably will not cause a black screen
//    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//        [self loadSomething];
//    });

//    This will not cause a black screen but not suitable for my use
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
//        [self loadSomething];
//    });

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self loadSomething];
    });
}

- (void)loadSomething
{
    NSLog(@"start long process");
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    while (-[start timeIntervalSinceNow] < 5) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details on the long process? I'm having a hard time figuring out why it must be run on the main thread, and I'd agree with Wain about moving it to a background thread. Perhaps more details could help us give you a better answer or figure out a way to run the code without blocking the UI.

Comment: Can you post the fadeout code?

Comment: The code is in the root view controller which shows some animation. The process is some data initialisation and version update. They are not designed to be run on background thread although they might run well on the background thread as of today.
The fadeout is iOS built-in feature. That would be nice if it can be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Consider why it must be on the main thread and come up with a way to move this processing or minimise it.

You should create a root view controller which displays the app default image and have that view controller displayed (probably with some animation or progress indication) until your processing has completed.

Comment: The code is in the root view controller which shows some animation. The process is some data initialisation and version update. They are not designed to be run on background thread although they might run well on the background thread as of today.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already on your main thread, then there is no need of getting the main thread asynchronously.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
});
```

The above code should be removed.

In case you want to do something or load something, then you should use

**performSelectorInBackground**

Hope this helps...

Comment: This part should be in the spinner animation delegate actually. Otherwise it will block the start of animation.